# How do I add a menu item to the main navigation from a custom module in Drupal 8?

Tags: routes, 8

For my custom Drupal 8 module I want to add a link to the default *main navigation* menu of the site.

What parent ID do I have to give to insert my menu item into the main menu?

I currently have the following config in `my_module.links.menu.yml`:

```
entity.sss_topic.collection:
  title: 'Topic: Listing'
  route_name: entity.sss_topic.collection
  description: 'List Topic'
  parent: main
```

But that only adds a menu item into the "Tools" menu (the same effect as specifying no *parent* whatsoever).
However, `parent: system.admin_structure` does work correctly.

Do I have the wrong parent ID? Or maybe a bug?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122241)? They go into a good amount of detail, perhaps you could edit the question to show where you're stuck?

Comment: Mainly I am looking for the right ID for the parent parameter in order to insert into the main navigation menu.

Comment: parent is not the menu, it is the parent menu link. Just leave parent out, main should be the default menu anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Seems like "Tools" is the default, however. Do you know how I can insert into a different menu?

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the "menu_name" key as said on : https://www.drupal.org/node/2122241

this example should work :

```
demo.demo:
  title: Demo Link
  description: 'This is a demo link'
  parent: main
  route_name: demo.demo
  menu_name: main
```

Comment: This solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Beware: [Build a Drupal 8 Module: Routing, Controllers and Menu Links](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-drupal-8-module-routing-controllers-menu-links/) is outdate, for example on demo.routing.yml is no longer _content, now is _controller.

Relate to add a menu item to the main navigation you can try with the parent `main`, like this:

```
demo.demo:
  title: Demo Link
  description: 'This is a demo link'
  parent: main
  route_name: demo.demo
```

Comment: tried that, unfortunately it's not giving the expected result. Updated my question now relating to this.

Comment: @Cibes you must Clear caches after change this. Do you did it?

Comment: Yes, did clear caches. Changes (e.g. title) are reflected but the item is added to the "Tools" menu.

Comment: Is weird because i test this and work for me. What is your version of Drupal 8?

Comment: using the beta9.
I am now using the workaround of displaying the "Tools" menu in place of the "Main Navigation" menu on my site ...

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm when set the "parent" property to be "main" in menu.link.yml will get your menu item display below in the default "Tools" as a submenu which is pretty weird. Anyone know how to make it happen to set up a menu item in the main menu?

If anyone come to this page just for add a simple menu item to the main menu list which created by a module configured by module.links.menu.yml.

Like I have a catalogue module which need to add a menu item titled "catalogue" to the main menu so I can get to that page quickly.

```
# add below code to catalogue.links.menu.yml
catalogue.page:
  title: 'Catalogue'
  description: 'some description about the catalogue menu item'
  route_name: catalogue.page
  weight: -20
  menu_name: main
  options:
    attributes:
      target: _blank
```

Note the "menu_name" defines which menu should the item be put in.

Comment: Currently, If I want to edit a menu, I have to edit each menu item separately by clicking the "edit" button. This is not user friendly. Is it possible that all menu items can be edited at once. There is a D7 module available, but nothing on D8. Does no budddy want this feature? Isn't it irritating. Here is the module. https://www.drupal.org/proj...

I guess such small things are the reason most of the people still prefer wordpress.