# where are menu item configurations stored?

Tags: 8, configuration

In drupal 8, which file holds the information of the menu items?  I do a config-export and do not see which file is changed when I change the menu items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Entity%21Menu.php/class/Menu/8.0.x) is a Entity, like a Node (sure, with some differences). There is a config and content, config you can export and import through UI, but not with content, this you will find only in DB.

Maybe you can find some modules to import/export content, but its not available at default install of Drupal 8.

Comment: well just as you can create a menu item by adding it to a view, is it possible to create a menu item with a module?

Comment: Well, yes, see one way here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/187287/54619

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_export looks like a promising module for this

Answer (score 0):

While parent menus are considered config, the items inside each menu are considered content. https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync allows you to export/import content as .yml files in a way similar to how configuration is synced.